# GIT - Maintain and only sync x files

Tags: git, git-branch

I am currently programming applications with game-maker, and I need to have two versions: -the demo; and -the full.

What I want to do is create 2 branches, one for each version, while the common files stay sync so i don't have to fix bugs 2 times. I have looked to forks but I don't seen that it is not what I want. Is there any way to do this?

Thank You.

Comment: Why two versions of the code? Isn't this mostly a matter of deployment, build and runtime configuration? (not containing all content in the demo)

Comment: We have some different code on the demo. Approximately 10% of the demo code is extra. And the full version has a lot of more functionalities

Answer (score 0):

i don't think there is an option just as you describe it, but maybe your best options is to create a project that actually contain 2 sub-projects: Main & Subs, while main has only one branch and subs has 2 branches: demo & full.
This way whenever you change Main it will affect both versions, moreover your can TAG main with a subproject how ever you like (e.g. Main002 with Demo004, Main003 with Full007)...

Hope that helped, i think also you must remember that Main and Subs must be 2 different folders.

Comment: Due to the gamemaker folder restrictions we cant do that. GameMaker has 1 folder for each time of data (ex: Objects, sprites, sound, etc) and in each folder we have some different files in each of them.